# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/user_sessions/......)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic, usersession

I'm super new to Ruby on Rails. I'm trying to make an authentication system using Authlogic (following this [tutorial](http://www.dixis.com/?p=352)). The error that I'm getting is right after I submit the login form:

```
No route matches "/user_sessions/%23%3CUserSession:0x103486aa8%3E"
```

Surprisingly the URL of the page right after the form is submitted which also brings up the error is:

```
http://localhost:3000/user_sessions/%23%3CUserSession:0x103486aa8%3E
```

I have no idea what I have done wrong and where that weird UserSession code thing is coming from!!!

This is how my login form looks like:

```
<% form_for @user_session do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :username %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :username%>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Here is my UserSession class:

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
  def to_key
    new_record? ? nil : [ self.send(self.class.primary_key) ]
  end
end
```

and the *create* action of my *UserSessionController*:

```
def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
    if @user_session.save
      flash[:notice] = "Login successful!"
      redirect_back_or_default root_path
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end
```

"redirect_back_or_default" method in *ApplicationController*:

```
def redirect_back_or_default(default)
  redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
  session[:return_to] = nil
end
```

And lastly everything related to user_sessions in *routes.rb*:

```
resources :user_sessions

match 'login' => "user_sessions#destroy", :as => :login
match 'logout' => "user_sessions#destroy", :as => :logout
```

These are the codes that *I* thought could be involved in getting that error. If I should add some more code to make it more clear please let me know.

Comment: Show us your UserSession Class.   Something is wrong there and it is not calling to_param on it properly.

Comment: I added the UserSession Class to the post.

Comment: Ok, why did you set to_key?  what are you trying to accomplish?  ah, the tutorial... it's out of date, you don't need that function...

Comment: Tried removing the function. Without it, I get the "undefined method `to_key' for #<UserSession: no credentials provided>" error in User_sessions#new. With the empty "to_key" function I get the previous error (No route matches "/user_sessions/%23%3CUserSession:0x103486aa8%3E")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first, you have a bad route:

```
    match '/login', :to => 'user_sessions#new', :as => 'login'
```

note the `new` instead of `destroy`

also, the to_key is not needed in later versions - I'm using rails 3 and don't have it in my UserSession Model.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. there is no need for the to_key function. But I also had to update my Gemfile and change the "gem 'authlogic'" to "gem 'authlogic', :git => 'git://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git', :branch => 'rails3'" and then "bundle install". My routes were actually fine in my original code, it was just a typo in the post only. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely need to change your route to not match login to destroy.
Here's the route setting I have... (from "Agile Web Development with Rails" example).

```
controller :user_sessions do

  get 'login' => :new
  post 'login' => :create
  delete 'logout' => :destroy
end
```